# CSS Overlay Issue - AdSense Block lays over my tags (Screenshot included)

Tags: php, html, css

I've updated my theme at my main site, [TweaksForGeeks.com](http://www.TweaksForGeeks.com), but as you can see in the image below I'm having an issue with my bottom AdSense block.

[image]

The AdSense block overlays the tags if it is an article that has enough tags (or long enough ones) to use more than one line. It looks proper if the tags are all on just one line.

I've fiddled with it a bit, and this block is set outside the tags div block, so I've no idea why it's doing this. Any ideas?

The offending page example is [here](http://www.tweaksforgeeks.com/q_and_a/2010/04/isass-exe-application-error-0xc00000005). Code is below.

CSS code is as follows:

```
#bottom-adsense {
    width:  468px;
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; }

    .post .post-meta {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    clear: both; }

    .rightn small a, .post-meta a {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #737373; }

    .rightn small, .post-meta {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #737373;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Page code is:

```
<div class="post-meta"><?php the_tags( __( '<span class="tag-links">Tags: ', 'wpbx' ), ", ", "</span>\n" ) ?></div>

                <div id="bottom-adsense">
                        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                                google_ad_client = "MY_PUB_ID";
                                /* 468x60 - Post Bottom */
                                google_ad_slot = "8415056823";
                                google_ad_width = 468;
                                google_ad_height = 60;
                                //-->
                        </script>
                        <script type="text/javascript"
                                src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
                        </script>
                </div>

    <div id="socialicons">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Currently reading <?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/twitter.png" alt="Tweet This!" />Tweet This</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="external,nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/facebook.png" alt="Share on Facebook" />Share on Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&url=<?php the_permalink();?>&title=<?php the_title();?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/digg.png" alt="Digg it!" />Digg This</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://del.icio.us/post?v=4&noui&jump=close&url=<?php the_permalink();?>&title=<?php the_title();?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/delicious.png" alt="Add to Delicious!" />Save to delicious</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/stumble.png" alt="Stumble it" />Stumble it</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/feed.png" alt="Subscribe by RSS" />RSS Feed</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
```

Comment: it is not a page code. it's PHP code. And PHP has nothing to do with page layout. Provide HTML code instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to remove the `height` property from the `.tag-links` ruleset, and add `clear: both` to the `#bottom-adsense` div.